# How to add a subView to tableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, subview

[image: This is my custom cell in storyboard. Note that I've assigned a tag of 123 for the prototype cell]

[image: This is my Implementation of the tableView's delegate and datasource methods]

However, I couldn't succeed in adding subviews to the tableView Cell. Please help me out!
A download link of my project is available [here.](http://filehosting.org/file/details/538107/sampleFile.zip)

Answer (score 0):

Do it in your 'cellForRowAtIndexPath'

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 22, 22)];
myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[cell addSubview:myView];
return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add it as a subview to the cell.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:"MyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

  if (nil == cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:"MyCell"];
  }
  UIView *aView = [UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
  [cell addSubview: aView];
  aView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
  return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your Mistake,With Red Line.

[image]

Find your Updated working Demo on Below Link,

[Sample Demo](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=80847472162323272644)

Comment: I'm getting blank cells, http://s10.postimg.org/hc4sj6ubd/Screen_Shot_2016_01_26_at_6_18_10_PM.png

Comment: have you download attached demo ?

Comment: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=80847472162323272644 from this link ?

Comment: Yes, I've ticked `isIntialViewController` in the storyboard. That's not the problem. The subViews are not being displayed. Is it some problem with my frameworks?

Comment: no , i have attached your project in this link. Download from it. http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=80847472162323272644

Comment: I've tried from that as well! I'm getting blank cells

Answer (score 0):

[image]In your project you have not set your ViewController as your initial view controller.

Other than this your code is working fine

Comment: I have downloaded his code and while running his code , there was only a black screen , then I a saw his view controller was not set to inital view controller , as soon as I added it as initial view controller and it was working fine

Comment: Ah, I didn't see the link in the question. My bad :D

Comment: Yea, I've forgotten to tick `isInitialViewController` in Storyboard. Anyhow, It's not working for me. Can you post a screenshot of your simulator?

Comment: But I'm getting blank cells! http://s10.postimg.org/hc4sj6ubd/Screen_Shot_2016_01_26_at_6_18_10_PM.png

Comment: have you made any further change...?

Comment: I am getting red cells as in the screen shot I have attached. You plz check it again that your code has not been changed or edited.

Comment: The problem from the beginning had been this. The subviews are not being displayed!

Comment: Quit your xcode delete app from your device or simulator open Xcode again, then clean your project and then run again.This might solve your issue